# Simplest way to display upcoming events from a public Google calendar?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, calendar, google-calendar-api

I have a public calendar on the site. I need to display upcoming events on the front page.

After spending the whole day on this I am about to give up. Google is disabling older API there is no documentation or anything. I am parsing the RSS feed:

```
http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/.../public/basic?futureevents=true
```

And grabbing `feed/entry/update` and `feed/entry/title` from XML. I read somewhere that `futureevents` will display upcoming events. However I get the list of older events.

Okay, then I tried to use API V3 https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/list

Here is the responce I get:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "usageLimits",
    "reason": "dailyLimitExceededUnreg",
    "message": "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup.",
    "extendedHelp": "https://code.google.com/apis/console"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup."
 }
}
```

I jumped through more hoops and installed their [ruby code sample](https://github.com/google/google-api-ruby-client-samples/tree/master/calendar)  as I need this for Rails site.

It sort of worked but it requires user to confirm access to their own calendar. I don't need that. Plus it seems that authentication only valid for a day.

The said calendar is public. It is being displayed in iframe on the site with xml and ical feed. All I need is to parse upcoming events to show them on front page.

What is the way to do it without authorization and other ridiculous stuff?

Comment: Either use a service account or use a public api key.  sorry cant help with ruby,   might give you something to Google until someone else answers.

Answer (score 1):

//This works for me! js:

```
var request = gapi.client.calendar.events.list({
      'calendarId': 'xxx',
      'timeMin': (new Date()).toISOString(),
      'showDeleted': false,
      'singleEvents': true,
      'maxResults': 1,
      'orderBy': 'startTime'
    });
    request.execute(function(resp) {}
```

Comment: If you were getting a list of instances of the same recurring event, the `singleEvents` and `orderBy` bits here is what solves the issue!

Answer (score 0):

Use this wizard to create a new API project: https://console.developers.google.com/start/api?id=calendar Then click on "create new key" (choose server key). Then do a request to https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars//events?key={YOUR_API_KEY} replacing the email and api key with your values.